Forms to Sharepoint error
I am using Forms to gather my data, then running it through Power Automate to get the information and place it into a sharepoint "spreadsheet". I am getting this error message. I have set the default numerical value on the sharepoint spreadhseet to 0, but am still getting this message. The issue is occurring when the form is being submitted with no data in a box that the spreadsheet is looking for a number. Is there a simple way to create a ITTT type command where if the field is blank, it enters a 0 on the spreadsheet?

OpenApiOperationParameterTypeConversionFailed The 'inputs.parameters'
of workflow operation 'Create_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not
valid. Error details: Input parameter
'item/CLCCensus_x0025__x0040_19_x003a_' is required to be of type
'Number/double'. The runtime value '""' to be converted doesn't have
the expected format 'Number/double'.


Please provide screenshot of your power automate action and values/formulas you have passed in that action it will help people to understand your issue quickly and you will get better solution in a quick manner.

You can write if condition to check if the value is empty then pass static value else pass that variable value to the column in your create item action.
You can try below formula for your required number type column as below:
I am assuming that your SharePoint list column is of number type:
if(empty(variables('YourVariableName')), 0, int(variables('YourVariableName')))
Note: Replace 'YourVariableName' with the name of your variable.
